# list view files in .NET

Tags: vb.net

Can anybody tell how to list view opened files in VB.NET.

The opened files should be seen in list view at the left part of GUI.

Comment: Do you want to show files your application has opened (File -> Open), or files open by all other applications running on the system?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually track open files, for example, by keeping a collection that contains their names. Once a new file is open, a new item containing the file path is added to the collection. When a specific file is closed, that item is removed from the collection.

**Note:** The collection I am talking about can have different data for specific files, not only file paths.

Given you have that collection, you can easily bind it to a ListView control.